# Leçon Un ou Une en titre de chapitre

Tags: accord, énumération, titres

Je corrige un ouvrage traduit de l'anglais et la traductrice a choisi d'intituler le premier chapitre "Leçon Un". Il est suivi de "Leçon Deux", etc. Cela est-il correct ? Serait-il préférable de choisir "Leçon no. 1" ?

Comment: *Leçon Un* ne respecte pas les règles de capitalisation françaises, ce doit être *Leçon un* ou *Leçon 1*

Answer (score 4):

Dans "Leçon un", "un" n'est pas article mais un [adjectif numéral](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/un#Adjectif_num%C3%A9ral). Plus spécéfiquement, il s'agit d'un [adjectif numéral cardinal](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjectif_num%C3%A9ral#Cardinal_substitu%C3%A9_%C3%A0_l%E2%80%99ordinal) substitué à un adjectif numéral ordinal (p.ex. "premier"/"première"). Dans ce cas, l'adjectif numéral n'est pas nécessairement variable. Wikipédia donne comme examples

> Chapitre ***un***, page ***vingt-et-un*** ou ***vingt-et-une*** (...)

La vidéo [Cours de français A2, leçon 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zmykUp8CHE) de Raffaella Fraomene, par exemple, dit aussi "leçon un".